# Scrapy - Crawl 4 level pages per item, can not go deep first

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to crawl the [township directory of China](http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/tjbz/tjyqhdmhcxhfdm/2016/index.html). The website is structured in 4 levels, which are **province page, city page, county page, and township page**. For example, on the province page, all the provinces are listed. If we click the link of one province, then it takes us to the city page and a list of the cities in that province is displayed.

I want each of my item to be a township. It includes town_name, town_id(gbcode), and corresponding county_name, city_name, prov_name. So the spider should collect information along the way as it goes deeper into the township page. However, my current approach using for loop does not seem to work. There is no problem with prov_name. But city and county name are mostly incorrect, they are always the last city/county in the list of their corresponding page. I think the problem is that the spider does not go deep enough, only go to parse_county request at the end of the loop. But, changing depth priority in the setting does not solve the problem.

```
---------- Sample Result --------
town_name, year, gbcode, city, province, county  
建国门街道办事处,2016,110101008000,市辖区,北京市,延庆区
东直门街道办事处,2016,110101009000,市辖区,北京市,延庆区
和平里街道办事处,2016,110101010000,市辖区,北京市,延庆区
前门街道办事处,2016,110101011000,市辖区,北京市,延庆区
崇文门外街道办事处,2016,110101012000,市辖区,北京市,延庆区



import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from admincode.items import AdmincodeItem

class StatsSpider(Spider):
    name = 'stats'
    allowed_domains = ['stats.gov.cn']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/tjbz/tjyqhdmhcxhfdm/{}/index.html'.format(year) for year in range(2009, 2010)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in self.parse_provincetr(response, response.selector.css(".provincetr")):
            yield item

    def get_text_href(self, td):
        if not td.xpath('a'):
            return td.xpath('text()').extract()[0], None
        else:
            return td.xpath('a/text()').extract()[0], td.xpath('a/@href').extract()[0]

    def parse_provincetr(self, response, trs):
        year_pattern = re.compile('(tjyqhdmhcxhfdm/)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])')
        year = year_pattern.search(response.url).group(2)
        for td in trs.xpath('td'):
            scraped = {}
            scraped['year'] = year
            scraped['prov_name'], href = self.get_text_href(td)
            url = response.urljoin(href)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_citytr,
                                meta={'scraped': scraped})

    def parse_2td(self, response, trs, var_name, nextparse):
        for tr in trs:
            scraped = response.meta['scraped']
            scraped[var_name], href = self.get_text_href(tr.xpath('td')[1])
            if nextparse:
                url = response.urljoin(href)
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=nextparse, meta={'scraped': scraped})
            else:
                item = AdmincodeItem()
                item['year'] = scraped['year']
                item['prov_name'] = scraped['prov_name']
                item['city_name'] = scraped['city_name']
                item['county_name'] = scraped['county_name']
                item['town_name'] = scraped['town_name']
                item['gbcode'], href = self.get_text_href(
                    tr.xpath('td')[0])
                yield item

    def parse_citytr(self, response):
        for city in self.parse_2td(response, response.selector.css(".citytr"), 'city_name', self.parse_countytr):
            yield city

    def parse_countytr(self, response):
        for county in self.parse_2td(response, response.selector.css(".countytr"), 'county_name', self.parse_towntr):
            yield county

    def parse_towntr(self, response):
        for town in self.parse_2td(response, response.selector.css(".towntr"), 'town_name', None):
            yield town
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking the output to be `{'province': '新疆', 'city_name': '塔城地区', 'city_code': '654200000000', 'county_name': '托里县', 'county_code': '654224000000', 'town_name': '兵团一七零团', 'town_code': '654224510000'}`

Comment: Yes, something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just made things a bit complex. This is a simple scraper, what you need to do is pass information from one page to another page using meta. Since meta is a dictionary in memory we need to make sure we create copies of the information for the items to come. For that we use `copy.deepcopy`. This will make sure data is not overwritten before yielding the items

Below is scraper which does that

```
class StatsSpider(Spider):
    name = 'stats'
    allowed_domains = ['stats.gov.cn']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/tjbz/tjyqhdmhcxhfdm/{}/index.html'.format(year) for year in range(2009, 2010)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css(".provincetr a"):
            name = item.xpath("./text()").extract_first().strip()
            link = item.xpath("./@href").extract_first().strip()
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_province, meta={'item':{'province':name}})

    def parse_province(self, response):
        meta = response.meta['item']

        for cityrow in response.css(".citytr"):
            city_link = cityrow.xpath("./td[2]/a/@href").extract_first()
            city_name = cityrow.xpath("./td[2]/a/text()").extract_first()
            city_code = cityrow.xpath("./td[1]/a/text()").extract_first()

            meta_new = deepcopy(meta)

            meta_new['city_name'] = city_name
            meta_new['city_code'] = city_code

            yield response.follow(city_link, callback=self.parse_city, meta = {'item':meta_new})

    def parse_city(self, response):

        meta = response.meta['item']

        for countyrow in response.css(".countytr"):
            county_link = countyrow.xpath("./td[2]/a/@href").extract_first()
            county_name = countyrow.xpath("./td[2]/a/text()").extract_first()
            county_code = countyrow.xpath("./td[1]/a/text()").extract_first()

            meta_new = deepcopy(meta)

            meta_new['county_name'] = county_name
            meta_new['county_code'] = county_code

            yield response.follow(county_link, callback=self.parse_county, meta = {"item": meta_new})

    def parse_county(self, response):

        meta = response.meta['item']

        for townrow in response.css(".towntr"):
            town_link = townrow.xpath("./td[2]/a/@href").extract_first()
            town_name = townrow.xpath("./td[2]/a/text()").extract_first()
            town_code = townrow.xpath("./td[1]/a/text()").extract_first()

            meta_new = deepcopy(meta)

            meta_new['town_name'] = town_name
            meta_new['town_code'] = town_code

            yield meta_new
```